# Xamarin.Mac Using security-scoped bookmarks

Tags: nsurl, xamarin.mac, appstore-sandbox, security-scoped-bookmarks

Microsoft's official documentation says:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/app-fundamentals/sandboxing#using-security-scoped-bookmarks

to try to access persistent outside of SandBox, but it doesn't work.

First, I use `NSSavePanel.SavePanel` according to the SandBox security policy and bookmark the URL that I can access.

```cs
using (var dlg = NSSavePanel.SavePanel)
{
  dlg.AllowedFileTypes = new[] { "zip" };
  dlg.Prompt = "Authenticate";

  if (dlg.RunModal() > 0)
  {
    NSError error;
    NSData url = dlg.Url.CreateBookmarkData(NSUrlBookmarkCreationOptions.WithSecurityScope, null, null, out error);
  }
}
```

And then I retrieve the access-authenticated bookmarks and make them accessible.

```cs
NSData data = new NSData();
NSUrl url = NSUrl.FromBookmarkData(data, NSUrlBookmarkResolutionOptions.WithSecurityScope, null, out bool isStale, out NSError error);

url.StartAccessingSecurityScopedResource();

//...

url.StopAccessingSecurityScopedResource();
```

However, the above `url` will only contain `null`, which will result in an error.

How can I make it work?

Do we need to put anything in the value of `NSData data` in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing some things. Your code

```
using (var dlg = NSSavePanel.SavePanel)
{
  dlg.Message = AppResources.DialogMessageSaveEncryptedFileName;
  dlg.AllowedFileTypes = new[] { "zip" };
  dlg.Prompt = "Authenticate";

  if (dlg.RunModal() > 0)
  {
    NSError error;
    //NSData url = dlg.Url.CreateBookmarkData(NSUrlBookmarkCreationOptions.WithSecurityScope, null, null, out error);
    NSData bookmark = dlg.Url.CreateBookmarkData(NSUrlBookmarkCreationOptions.WithSecurityScope, null, null, out error);
  }
}
```

The `dlg.Url` is the url you want to access.
What you get back from `dlg.Url.CreateBookmarkData()` is the encoded bookmark data. You can store this data anyway you like to persist it across app launches. For example in UserDefaults
Storing:

```
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults["bookmark"] = bookmark; 
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();
```

Later retrieving:

```
NSData bookmark = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.DataForKey("bookmark");
```

This is the data you
put into `NSUrl.FromBookmarkData` to get the url back.

```
//NSData data = new NSData();
//NSUrl url = NSUrl.FromBookmarkData(data, NSUrlBookmarkResolutionOptions.WithSecurityScope, null, out bool isStale, out NSError error);
NSUrl url = NSUrl.FromBookmarkData(bookmark, NSUrlBookmarkResolutionOptions.WithSecurityScope, null, out bool isStale, out NSError error);    
url.StartAccessingSecurityScopedResource();

//...

url.StopAccessingSecurityScopedResource();
```

Also if you need to keep using the access pay attention to the `isStale` return value from `CreateBookmarkData`. If it return true you need to refresh the bookmark from the url with `url.CreateBookMarkData` and replace the stored bookmark with the new one.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code helped me understand how it works better.